# Flutter Hive model have enum type but not able to put/set value in enum with hive-field

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I want a hivemodel class which is contain enum as field but hive is not able to put set value.

*CONTACTTYPE* is `enum`:

[image: click here]

[image: click here]

```
@freezed
@HiveType(typeId: 7, adapterName: "FriendGroupEntityAdapter")
@freezed

class FriendsGroupEntity with _$FriendsGroupEntity {

  const factory FriendsGroupEntity({
 @HiveField(0)  int userId,
  @HiveField(1)  @Default(CONTACTTYPE.loop) CONTACTTYPE contactType,
  @HiveField(2)   String contact,
  @HiveField(3)   int id,
  @HiveField(4)   int value,
  @HiveField(5)   int value2,
  @HiveField(6)   int value3,
  @HiveField(7)   int value7,
});
```

Here `CONTACTTYPE.loop` is an enum and I want to store it into hive, and got an error which I attach.

Is there any way for enum in hive?

Comment: Can you put code segment in the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow this approach

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
    
    part 'myrepresentation.g.dart';
    
    @HiveType(typeId: 1)
    class FriendsGroupEntity extends HiveObject {
      @HiveField(0)
      final String id;
    
      @HiveField(1)
      final Foo foo;
      MyRepresentation({required this.id, required this.foo});
    }
    
    @HiveType(typeId: 2)
    enum Foo {
      @HiveField(0)
      foo,
      @HiveField(1)
      bar,
    }
```

check this reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058211/how-to-handle-enum-in-hive-flutter)