# How to handle enum in Hive Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, flutter-hive

I have an enum in my model class:

```dart
MyRepresentation { list, tabs, single }
```

I have already added an adapter and registered it.
I have given it a proper type id and fields.

It gives error:

> HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: MyRepresentation. Did you forget to register an adapter?

Comment: Hi @rahulVFlutterAndroid yes eager to know please share

Comment: are you still need it?

Comment: I had am enum field saved without any additional effort within the class nine months ago. And now it requires an additional adapter... Thinking to use `int` or `string` property for storage and additional wrapper property as  an enum representation. However Dominic's second advise is fine too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you register the enum too or just the model? Say your model file *myrepresentation.dart* looks like this:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'myrepresentation.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class MyRepresentation extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String id;

  @HiveField(1)
  final Foo foo;
  MyRepresentation({required this.id, required this.foo});
}

@HiveType(typeId: 2)
enum Foo {
  @HiveField(0)
  foo,
  @HiveField(1)
  bar,
}
```

Then you generate you type adapters and initialize **both** of them in your main:

```
void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  ...
  Hive.registerAdapter(MyRepresentationAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(FooAdapter());

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

If you have done this and it is still giving you problems, you could try to put the enum in its own file and write its own `part` statement.

If this still isn't working I suggest simply storing the enum as int yourself in the `TypeAdapter` `read()` and `write()` methods like this:

```
@override
MyRepresentation read(BinaryReader reader) {
  return MyRepresentation(
    reader.read() as String,
    Foo.values[reader.read() as int]
  );
}

@override
void write(BinaryWriter writer, MyRepresentation obj) {
  writer.write(obj.id);
  writer.write(obj.foo.index);
}
```

Comment: Just a quick fix, your `id` and your `Foo` object in `MyRepresentation` should be annotated with HiveField and not HiveType.